# standard type conversion of an int to an unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I tried to change the type of a value like -1 (int) into an unsigned int. I tried this code

```
int main () {
 int a = -1;
unsigned int b;
b = a;
  cout << b;
  return 0;
}
```

the result was :
**4294967295**
but I assumed that the -1 as a 32 bit int is like:
10000000000000000000000000000001
and when it's going to be changed to unsigned it should be:
1*2^31 + 1*2^0 = **2147483649**.
what is wring with my thought?

Comment: See here (Two's complement): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.

Comment: "but I assumed that the -1 as a 32 bit int is like: 10000000000000000000000000000001" - And did you check this assumption? Try googling "negative number representation" or something like this.

Comment: In two's complement (which is ubiquitous) -1 is 111..111.

Answer (score 3):

> what is wring with my thought?

1. Your assumption about representation of signed integers is wrong.

   You've described one possible representation, called "sign and magnitude". This representation was used by some systems built in the 1950's and 60's. All modern computer systems use another representation called "two's complement". In such representation -1 will be represented by all bits 1.
2. Your assumption that the representation affects the result of the conversion is wrong.

   Whether a computer system uses particular sign representation or not, the behaviour of the conversion in C++ is same as on other systems. See the next segment.
3. Your assumption about the result of the conversion is wrong.

   When you convert an unrepresentable value to unsigned, the result will be the representable value that is congruent with the original value modulo M, where M is the number of representable values in the usigned type which is maximum representable value +1.

   -1 is congruent with 4294967295 modulo 4294967296. This result is to be expected on those systems where the size of `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Even if  the `int` was encoded as *binary* "10000000000000000000000000000001" (sign-magnitude), `b` is still `4294967295`.

Conversion of an `int` to `unsigned` is not based on the encoding used by `int`.  Instead, since the negative `-1` is an out-of-range `unsigned` value, the maximum `unsigned` value + 1 is added until the sum is within range.

Nothing to do with 2's complement or the other more rare `int` encodings. (IIRC non-2's complement is only allowed in older C++ these days.)